# Generic Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote a code for a hover functionality. Now, I am asking myself how to make this code generic in order to show different divs when hovering over a different link. The JavaScript code is as follows:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var moveLeft = 20;
        var moveDown = 10;
        $('a#trigger').hover(function(e) {
            $('div#purpose').show();
        }, function() {
            $('div#purpose').hide();
        });
        $('a#trigger').mousemove(function(e) {
        $("div#purpose").css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The div I call is as follows:

```
<!-- Purpose: Hover Popup -->
<div class= id="purpose">
    <h3>Purpose</h3>
    <p>
        Test
    </p>
</div>
```

Furthermore, I added some CSS style

```
<!-- Style for Hovering -->
<style type="text/css">
    div#purpose {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        width: 280px;
        padding: 10px;
        background: #eeeeee;
        color: #000000;
        border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
        font-size: 90%;
    }
</style>
```

Could anybody tell me how to make this code generic in order to add further divs which are called from another link?

Comment: Where is the trigger tag?

Comment: Use classes instead of an _id_ to attach the listeners, set an attribute, e.g. `data-target` on the _"trigger" `<a>`_ to help you be specific about which you want to show

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should add the jquery tag to your question since most of your script consists of jquery method calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of custom `data-*` attributes in your HTML, and use classes to target a generalized group of elements, ex:

```
<a class="trigger" data-target="purpose" />
```

And the JS

```
$(".trigger").hover(function(e) {
  var elemToShow = $(this).data("target");
  $("#" + elemToShow).show();
}, function() {
  var elemToShow = $(this).data("target");
  $("#" + elemToShow).show();
}).mousemove(function(e) {
  var elemToShow = $(this).data("target");
  $("#" + elemToShow).css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added this JS code. Furthermore I added the custom data attributes in my HTML on each div like indicated by you above. I also adjusted the CSS. However, nothing is being displayed....is it correct for the CSS to write the following: div#target {.....? thanks for your answer

Comment: Are you still having the issue?

Comment: is it correct to write data("target")? maybe it should be "data-target"?

Comment: It's correct, the css should stay the same pointing to div#purpose

Comment: How would it be done to make the CSS generic as well? Purpose is one div item appearing on the webpage...there will be different ones as well...

Comment: Hi tymeJV, thanks a lot for your help first. However, I am still facing some problems with your code. I posted the problem again (you can see it if you scroll down on this page). Thanks for your help and answers.

Comment: @dwin90 -- Your target attribute is missing an `=` sign - and it should be `data-target` - and give all your elements that are being targetted a generic class, then use the CSS to target that class (`#scope` and `#purpose` should get a class added, like `.hover-target` - then CSS that.

Answer (score 2):

Create a javascript function and pass in the variables (e.g. link and div)

```
function foo($link, $div){
    var moveLeft = 20;
    var moveDown = 10;

    $link.hover(function(e) {
      $div.show();

    }, function() {
      $div.hide();
    });

    $link.mousemove(function(e) {
      $div.css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
    });
}
```

For your existing behaviour call the following for example:

```
foo($('a#trigger'), $("div#purpose"));
```

This will actually be slightly better for performance as you'll be using the same jQuery reference each time. However depending on how you're actually planning on using this, having a seperate function call each time might not be the best way.

For example if you wish to use this on dynamic data it wouldn't be sensible to make static calls to a function each time.

Answer (score 0):

You could build your trigger elements in a way that they hold the information about what element to show:

```
<a class="trigger" data-show="purpose">...</a>
```

Then you initialize them all at once like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.trigger').hover(function() {
        var elementId = $(this).data('show');
        $('#'+elementId).show();
    }, function() {
        var elementId = $(this).data('show');
        $('#'+elementId).hide();
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any JavaScript or jQuery at all for this--you can simply use CSS with the [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ahover) pseudo-class.

```css
.menu {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.menuItem {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu .trigger + .purpose {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.menu .trigger:hover + .purpose, .menu .trigger + .purpose:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menuItem">
    <a href="#" class="trigger">Trigger 1</a>
    <div class="purpose">
      <h3>Purpose 1</h3>
      <p>
        Test 1
      </p>    
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menuItem">
    <a href="#" class="trigger">Trigger 2</a>
    <div class="purpose">
      <h3>Purpose 2</h3>
      <p>
        Test 2
      </p>    
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menuItem">
    <a href="#" class="trigger">Trigger 3</a>
    <div class="purpose">
      <h3>Purpose 3</h3>
      <p>
        Test 3
      </p>    
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menuItem">
    <a href="#" class="trigger">Trigger 4</a>
    <div class="purpose">
      <h3>Purpose 4</h3>
      <p>
        Test 4
      </p>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello. In my application I have some problems using CSS apart from the HTML code. Could you tell me the correct syntax for inserting this CSS styling in the HTML code? Thanks a lot

Comment: Just put it in a [`<style>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) tag